# How do you programmatically generate a sphere?

Tags: rendering, geometry, procedural-generation

Could someone please explain how it would be possible to create a sphere vertices, indices and texture coordinates? There is a surprising lack of documentation on how to do so and it is something that I am interested in learning.

I have tried the obvious, googling, looking on gamedev.net, etc. However, nothing covers the generations of spherical points, indexing them, and texturing.

Comment: Worth noting, for some simple purposes a perfectly fine "sphere" is a quad with a circular texture facing the camera.

Answer (score 36):

There are two general approaches:

[image]

The leftmost is termed the uv-sphere and the rightmost an icosphere.

GLUT tends to use the uv approach: look at the function `glutSolidSphere()` in the [freeglut sourcecode](http://freeglut.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/freeglut/trunk/freeglut/freeglut/src/freeglut_geometry.c?revision=926&view=markup).

Here is an excellent article on producing an icosphere: http://blog.andreaskahler.com/2009/06/creating-icosphere-mesh-in-code.html

> The uv-sphere looks like a globe. For many purposes it is perfectly
>   fine, but for some use cases, e.g. if you want to deform the sphere,
>   it is disadvantageous that the density of vertices is greater around
>   the poles. Here the icosphere is better, its vertices are distributed
>   evenly.

You may also find this interesting: http://kiwi.atmos.colostate.edu/BUGS/geodesic/text.html it describes an approach to organising the faces into zones.

http://vterrain.org/Textures/spherical.html gives an excellent description of how you might choose to texture them.

Comment: While the general idea is good, subdividing a [Schläfli {3,5} polytope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schl%C3%A4fli_symbol) isn't the only way to do it. Generally, I prefer to work with the Schläfli {4,*} family ({4,3} in case of a sphere) for UV-mapping purposes.

Comment: Finely tessellated icosahedral spheres are a bit more expensive to generate because of the need to recursively subdivide the faces.

Answer (score 10):

There are 2 ways to do it:

1. Walk theta and phi in spherical coordinates, generate faces and tris
2. Create an icosahedron and recursively subdivide faces until desired tessellation reached.

### Sphere using spherical coordinates walk

For the first way, you just use a double nested for to walk theta and phi.  As you walk theta and phi, you spin triangles to create your sphere.

[image]

The code that does it will look something like this:

```
for( int t = 0 ; t < stacks ; t++ ) // stacks are ELEVATION so they count theta
{
  real theta1 = ( (real)(t)/stacks )*PI ;
  real theta2 = ( (real)(t+1)/stacks )*PI ;

  for( int p = 0 ; p < slices ; p++ ) // slices are ORANGE SLICES so the count azimuth
  {
    real phi1 = ( (real)(p)/slices )*2*PI ; // azimuth goes around 0 .. 2*PI
    real phi2 = ( (real)(p+1)/slices )*2*PI ;

    //phi2   phi1
    // |      |
    // 2------1 -- theta1
    // |\ _   |
    // |    \ |
    // 3------4 -- theta2
    //

    //vertex1 = vertex on a sphere of radius r at spherical coords theta1, phi1
    //vertex2 = vertex on a sphere of radius r at spherical coords theta1, phi2
    //vertex3 = vertex on a sphere of radius r at spherical coords theta2, phi2
    //vertex4 = vertex on a sphere of radius r at spherical coords theta2, phi1

    // facing out
    if( t == 0 ) // top cap
      mesh->addTri( vertex1, vertex3, vertex4 ) ; //t1p1, t2p2, t2p1
    else if( t + 1 == stacks ) //end cap
      mesh->addTri( vertex3, vertex1, vertex2 ) ; //t2p2, t1p1, t1p2
    else
    {
      // body, facing OUT:
      mesh->addTri( vertex1, vertex2, vertex4 ) ;
      mesh->addTri( vertex2, vertex3, vertex4 ) ;
    }
  }
}
```

So note above, its important to wind the top cap and bottom cap using only tris, not quads.

### Icosahedral sphere

TO use an icosahedron, you just generate the points of the icosahedron and then wind up triangles from it.  The [vertices of an icosahedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosahedron) sitting at the origin are:

```
(0, ±1, ±φ)
(±1, ±φ, 0)
(±φ, 0, ±1)
where φ = (1 + √5) / 2
```

You then have to just look at a diagram of an icosahedron and wind faces from those verts.  I already have code that does it [here](https://github.com/superwills/gtp/blob/master/gtp/geometry/Icosahedron.cpp).

Comment: any ideas how to get the half body, like from theta=pi/4 to theta=3pi*4? Like this image: i.stack.imgur.com/Jjx2c.jpg I've been spending days on this couldn't solve it.

Answer (score 3):

If the points don't have to be locally uniform, but should be globally uniform, and don't have to follow any set pattern, you can use a variant of dart-throwing algorithm to distribute *n* points on a sphere with radius *r*, on average *dist* points apart. These values are then roughly:

1. If you want to have a specific amount of vertices:

   - *n* = (desired amount of vertices)
   - *dist* = 2 × *r* × √(*π* / *n*)
2. If you want to have a specific average distance between the vertices:

   - *n* = 4 × *π* × (*r* / *dist*)<sup>2</sup>
   - *dist* = (desired average distance)

In the simplest case, you can then uniformly pick points at random by picking two uniformly distributed variables *u* and *v* from (0, 1) and calculating the polar coordinates from them according to the formulas *θ* = 2 × *π* × *u* and *ϕ* = arc cos (2 × *v* - 1); then dismissing any points which lie too near to the already picked points. For a slightly more complex and significantly better-performing algorithm, see "[Dart Throwing on Surfaces](http://peterwonka.net/Publications/2009.EGF.Cline.PoissonOnSurfaces.pdf)" by Cline, Jeschke, White, Razdan and Wonka.

After you picked your first four points (assuming no three of them are *degenerate*, that is - they don't lie on the same great circle, but that's highly unlikely), you can create four faces between them, and each time you add a new point, you can split the face it belongs to accordingly into three sub-faces.

For texturing purposes you can then map the points to a cube map.